# jQuery Mobile Ajax post cross domain data Allow apps only setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a trial app using phonegap and jquery/jmobile.

Success on exchange data between server and apps using jquery get and post.

For now I am using `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

I want to ensure the server only can be accessed through my apps. Not `* All apps or domains`.

What method should be used?

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: according to the docs for the Allow-Origin header you have to list the domains, or use *. If it's an app, you likely won't know the domain in advance, hence the use of *. Therefore to restrict access you will need to implement some form of authentication or authorization (perhaps a token included in the request) to ensure it's your app which is making the request.